# How can I change the return value of a class constructor in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constructor

I have a class, Foo.  I want to be able to pass the constructor a Foo instance, foo and get the same instance back out.

In other words, I want this test to pass:

```
class Foo; end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Foo.new(foo)

assert_equal foo, bar
```

Anyone know how I can do that?  I tried this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(arg = nil)
    return arg if arg
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Foo.new(foo)

assert_equal foo, bar  # => fails
```

but it doesn't work.

Help?

**EDIT**

Because a number of people have asked for my rationale:

I'm doing rapid analysis of lots of data (many TB) and I am going to have a lot of instances of a lot of objects.  For some of these objects, it doesn't make sense to have two different instances with the same data.  For example, one such object is a "window" (as in temporal window) object that has two properties:  start time and end time.  I want to be able to use the constructor in any of these ways and get a window object back:

```
window = Window.new(time_a, time_b)
window = Window.new([time_a, time_b])
window = Window.new(seconds_since_epoch_a, seconds_since_epoch_b)
window = Window.new(window_obj)
window = Window.new(end => time_b, start => time_a)
...
```

Some other object that needs a window might be instantiated this way:

```
obj = SomeObj.new(data => my_data, window => window_arg)
```

I don't necessarily know what's in window_arg, and I don't really care -- it will accept any single argument that can be interpreted by the Window constructor.  In the case of already having a Window instance, I'd rather just use that instance.  But the job of interpreting that seems like a concern of the Window constructor.  Anyway, as I mentioned I'm churning through many TB of data and creating lots of instances of things.  If a window object gets passed around, I want it just to be recognized as a window object and used.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
def Foo.new(arg=nil)
  arg || super
end
```

Answer (score 33):

By [**definition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)), constructors are meant to return a newly created object of the class they are a member of, so, no you should **not** override this behavior.

Besides, in Ruby, `new` calls `initialize` somewhere within its method body, and its return value is ignored, so either way the value you return from `initialize` will not be returned from `new`.

With that said, I think that in your case, you might want to create a factory method that will return different `Foo` objects based on arguments passed to the factory method:

```
class Foo
  def self.factory(arg = nil)
    return arg if arg.kind_of? Foo
    Foo.new
  end
end
foo = Foo.factory
bar = Foo.factory(foo)

assert_equal foo, bar #passes
```

Answer (score 16):

`initialize` is called by `new` which ignores its return value. Basically the default `new` method looks like this (except that it's implemented in C, not in ruby):

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &blk)
    o = allocate
    o.send(:initialize, *args, &blk)
    o
  end
end
```

So the newly allocated object is returned either way, no matter what you do in `initialize`. The only way to change that is overriding the `new` method, for example like this:

```
class Foo
  def self.new(arg=nil)
    if arg
      return arg
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

However I'd strongly advise against this since it runs counter to many expectations that people have when calling `new`:

- People expect `new` to return a new object. I mean it's even called `new`. If you want a method that does not always create a new object, you should probably call it something else.
- At the very least people expect `Foo.new` to return a `Foo` object. Your code will return whatever the argument is. I.e. `Foo.new(42)` would return 42, an Integer, not a `Foo` object. So if you're going to do this, you should at the very least only return the given object, if it is a `Foo` object.

Answer (score 2):

Does not work for:

```ruby
class Some
    def self.new( str )
        SomeMore.new( str )
    end
end
```

`#` the Some is parent of SomeMore
class SomeMore  < Some
    def initialize( str )
        @str = str
    end
end

Comment: You can edit to fix your grammatical errors (Such as Does instead of Dose.)

Answer (score 1):

For this particular use case, it might be better to use one of these approaches.

```
class Foo
    def self.new(args=nil)
        @@obj ||= super(args)
    end
end


class Foo
    def self.new(args)
      @@obj = super(args)
    end

    def self.new
      @@obj
    end

end
```

This allows you to have only a single object that gets created that can be used universally, but returns an object of the `Foo` class, making it fall more inline with standard expectations of a `new` method, as Jacob pointed out.